# Reading values assigned to annotated field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

i am very new to JAVA 8 and SPRING MVC . I have a java bean which is a POJO with setter and getter. My Spring web service using reflection maps the request parameters to the POJO.
I want to do input validation using annotation. I have a requirement were i need to read all the values of the annotated field and check atleast one value is provided. I wrote a sample code.... BUT NOT SURE HOW TO GET THE VALUES THAT ARE ASSIGNED TO A FIELD. Please do share sample code if you have:

```
public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

    boolean canProceed = false;
    for(Field field  : DocumentSearchRequest_global.class.getDeclaredFields())
    {

        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ValidDocumentModifiedDate.class))
            {
                String name = field.getName();
      //IAM ABLE TO GET THE NAME OF THE FIELD
                System.out.println("1.name :   "+ name); 
                System.out.println("2.            "+field.getType().getName());


            }
    }
   // Method[] method = DocumentSearchRequest_global.class.getDeclaredMethods();
   for (Method  method :DocumentSearchRequest_global.class.getDeclaredMethods() )
   {
       System.out.println(method.getName() );
      //ABLE TO GET NAME OF THE GETTER AND SETTER METHODS IN THE POJO
     //CAN U SUGGEST HOW TO READ THE VALUE OF A PARTICULAR FIELD.. EITHER BY       //GETTING THE VALUE FROM THE GET METHOD??? ...
   }
```

Comment: i know that i can use method.invoke(DocumentSearchRequest_global_instance) but my question is that is there a way to pass the instance of the current instance of the class at run time as my requirement is read the values assigned to each field at run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values by calling `method.invoke(Object, Object...)` where first parameter is your class instance on which method is to be executed and second variable arguments are arguments of the method. In your case it'll be null or empty. Here is simple code snippet `Object value = method.invoke(DocumentSearchRequest_global_instance);`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Suken ... but can u please tell me how do i pass DocumentSearchRequest_global_instance to the method.

Comment: I am guessing that it will be available in your context or session or as a bean. Please note that you cannot get value of properties without invoking methods on the instance.